# The django modal window don't stay with content inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm really lost here.
I build the django model window and when i start to write the content inside, everything it's out from the modal window. I have no idea what's going on.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVOKJ.png)

The modal code

```
<div id="modal_window_new_register" class="modal_window_new_register" >
    <div class="new_register_modal">
        <button class="close" id="close">X</button>
    </div>

    Test Test Test Test Test

</div>
```

The model css code

```
/* Modal window */

.modal_window_new_register{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00000080;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 9999;

    overflow: auto;
}

.new_register_modal{
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 450px;
    height: 95vh;
    background-color: #ffff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff96;
    font-size: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal_window_new_register.open_new_register_modal{
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the css like this, you should put the text inside the `.new_register_modal` div. That should solve your problem.

Comment: And about the close botton ?? I writing then inside the .new_register_model, but it out of the model window??

Comment: @PauloHenriqueASA place it inside the parent div (#modal_window_new_register) and change the top and right css proprties to 10px each.